# HTML/JS Validation

Tags: javascript, html

How can I expand the javascript code so that the examination number can only have a maximum length of 4 digits entered and the user cannot type anymore. Also how can I expand the code so that the examination field isn't left out. Aswell for the radio buttons I want to add a validation so if someone checks any box e.g GCSE a message will come up saying you have ticked (radio button ticked)
 Thanks in advance

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Exam entry</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
var result = true;
var msg="";
if (document.ExamEntry.name.value=="") {
msg+="You must enter your name \n";
document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
document.getElementById('name').style.color="red";
result = false;
}
if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value=="") {
msg+="You must enter the subject \n";
document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
document.getElementById('subject').style.color="red";
result = false;
}
if(msg==""){
return result;
}
{
alert(msg)
return result;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
<form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">
<table width="50%" border="0">
<tr>
<td id="name">Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="subject">Subject</td>
<td><input type="text" name="subject" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="name">Examination number</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Examination number" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm();" /></td>
<td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<p> Please select <b>ONE</b> button.</br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="GCSE">GCSE<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="AS" checked>AS<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="A2" checked>A2<br>
</body>
</html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Success message</title>
</head>
<body>
<H1> You entered all the data required </H1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pretty basic stuff I'd say. A simple Google search would throw up a plethora of tutorials for you

Comment: just add maxlength  and required to the input field, no need for js here

Comment: `maxlength` is fine. But what if the user is on IE9 or less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `maxlength`:

```
<input type="text" id="test" name="test" maxlength="4"/>
```

or in JavaScript you can do this:

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8j6Ts/1/)**

```
var input = document.getElementById("test");

input.oninput = function(){
    if (input.value.length > 4)
    {
        var str = input.value;
        str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
        input.value = str;
        alert("Some error message here");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" name="Examination number" maxlength="4"/> for maxlength
```

put this in form onsubmit="return validateForm();"

check this for javascript validation

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

learn yourself.

Comment: Thanks for this. I need help with the validation of examination number so a message comes up if its left out and I need help with the radio buttons.

Comment: we are here for help if u stuck some where not to do the code for you.learn your self. and do some google.

Comment: a quick google search gives me this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19904/TEXTAREA-Max-length-check